# Как добавить в Settings свой тип данных?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Есть класс:

```
public class Hotkey  {
     public string name;
     public List<Key> hotkey;

     public Hotkey(string name, List<Key> hotkey) {
         this.name = name;
         this.hotkey = hotkey;
     }
}
```

Однако в Settings.settings можно хранить данные только стандартных типов (int, string, ...). Каким образом данный класс можно добавить в настройки программы?

[image: Settings]

Comment: На английском staсkoverflaw подобный вопрос поднимался несколько раз. Вот две ссылки, которые выглядят довольно полезными https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967575/add-custom-type-in-settings-settings   и  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000625/add-a-collection-of-a-custom-class-to-settings-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл настроек состоит из основного файла и файла `ИмяФайлаНастроекDesigner.cs`, вам нужно как обычно добавить переменную в файл настроек, а затем в "дизайнере" вручную переписать её тип на необходимый вам. Там интуитивно все должно быть понятно.

Пример:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
public List<CalcMap> List
{
get {
        return ((List<CalcMap>)(this["List"]));
    }
set {
        this["List"] = value;
    }
}
```

Изначально это была строковая переменная, а я переписал на `List<CalcMap>`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Теперь я смогу спать спокойно! Все вроде работает и все делается очень просто.